# "This certificate was signed by an untrusted issuer" problem after updating to El Capitan

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keychain, certificate

[image]

Most of the https connections returns that. Most of them is signed by Symantec. But not all. I tried to google the problem, but with no luck, seems like I only the one who experiencing this problem.

I checked apple's certificate with https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html and all seem to be correct.

Some of the blocked sites can't be reached by Chrome due to HSTS: 
[image]

This happens when I open iTunes: [image]
After clicking "continue" there are appears more such windows, most of them on apple.com domain just with different subdomains.

Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue. It is certificate related on your own mac. 
Your machine has expired certificates which can be deleted using: 
- applications > utilities > keychain Access.

- Select a) Keychain: Login and b) Category: Certificates

- Scroll each certificate and if it has expired delete it.

I found the answer including instruction and images via link
http://tiffanybbrown.com/2015/10/cant-connect-to-itunes-app-store-https-sites-el-capitan-upgrade/

Comment: How can web masters stop this happening to their users?

Comment: Symantec is no longer a trusted certificate authority.

Answer (score 0):

Apple is un-trustingSymantec certificates now.  See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208860

The original problem with Symantec: https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/blog/Security-Bytes/Symantecs-untrusted-certificates-How-many-are-still-in-use